# Layer from Autocad file do not show correct color on Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Im using Forge Viewer to publish my Autocad file, but it seem not show correct color. For example i have layer with white color (rgb(255,255,255)), it show grey instead, sometime it not correct line weight too. Is there any way to make it right? [image]

Comment: Can you share model to `aps[dot]help[at]autodesk.com `?, I have created a MTEXT on drawing with white color layer, I can see that color is displayed correctly. Which version of Viewer you are using ?
https://pasteboard.co/PSIKsjzB2MDX.png